# UFPDF2, UFPDF and FPDF AddFont() error

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, bitrix

it is my first post on the stackoverflow. My problem is generate PDF-file about shop item on-fly, by the clicking on button. Site working on php, bitrix. I trying to use FPDF, and next UFPDF and UFPDF2 - scripts. I make font-files by utilites, which donwload width main files. I have FreeSerif.php, FreeSerif.z and FreeSerif.ctg.z

I include them in script:

```
$pdf->AddFont('FreeSerif', '', 'FreeSerif.php');
```

Script generate pdf-file, but pages is 0/0, this document can be create incorrect. Where may be problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most PDF-generator libraries there is a requirment `mbstring.func_overload 0`
Try to add something like this in httpd.conf, path to script where PDF generated:

```
    <Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/path/reports>
            php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 0
    </Directory>
```

then restart apache